# Why can't you redirect to some URLs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, redirect, paypal

I have been getting help from Paypal technical support on tracking down a strange bug where some users are not redirected after payment to our site for some reason, but most users are.

The really helpful support guy at Paypal said the following:

> We have checked those 5 PayKey respectively, it showed that all the
>   customers/buyers were US users. And in AP-6PC49991TU1544250, the
>   return URL was [REDACTED], we visit it successfully on PC(with a VPN),
>   but failed on a iPhone(We are here in China). To avoid/fix this issue,
>   please make sure that this URL can be visited by US users.

I am wondering how it is possible that in some locations or devices a URL can not be redirected to?

One thing to note is that the page being redirected to also performs a redirect using `Codeigniter` redirect method.

## Update

So Paypal redirects to a page, it receives a `302` with a location and then I guess it's up to the browser to redirect. Maybe some browsers do not support this?

Comment: I suppose paypal page is https, are you redirecting to https or http? Might be some security setting.

Comment: @Marek We set the redirect URL before payment using Paypal API and we specify `https`.

Comment: Can you reproduce this yourselves, on an iPhone? I wouldn't necessarily trust test results from behind the [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Shield_Project). (And how many of your customers *aren't* in the US? Is all five customers with the problem being in the US in any way statistically significant?)

Comment: @MattGibson I can't reproduce this with my iPhone and it seems to be effecting a decent amount of users judging by email complaints of not being redirected, most of these users tend to be on a mobile device too. 70% of our users are based in the US.

Comment: And you've checked your server access/error logs for relevant stuff? (If you could track down the attempted access that definitely failed from China in your logs it might give you a clue...)

Answer (score 0):

You may have an error with your Intermediate Certificate not being compliant with certain mobile operating systems. Personally, I check my client's SSL with [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html). The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection, but if the SSL is non-compliant with the chain provided by the issuer and attempting to perform a redirect; it will fail. Contact your issuer if you receive this error to supplement an up-to-date Intermediate Certificate.

Comment: I checked my domain with the SSL checker. It showed all green. So it must be another issue other than SSL. At least we can rule that out.